# transpose column to row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, union, transpose

I want to transpose the resulting column to row without using ranking method in MYSQL.

```
select pid , phone  from mt where pid = 1 ; 

Result :

pid   phone
1     556
1     678
```

I want it in this format :

```
pid   phone1   phone2
1       556     678
```

Similarly if  execute a query which has only 1 value like the one below

select pid , phone  from mt where pid = 2 ;

it should result in both the columns phone1 and phone2 but phone2 column should be null like the following .

```
  pid   phone1     phone2
   2     123        NULL
```

How to proceed further ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only two values, you can use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select pid, min(phone) as phone_1,
       (case when min(phone) <> max(phone) then max(phone) end) as phone_2
from t
group by pid;
```